# Nexmo not sending to US numbers

Tags: api, laravel-4, vonage

Framework: **Laravel 4.2**

API: **Nexmo**

Library: **christian-giupponi/nexmo** https://github.com/ChristianGiupponi/Laravel-4-Nexmo

I have already deposit $10 in my account which means its not demo anymore.

```
<?php

        $response = Nexmo::sendSMS('Amazon Company', $text_data['contact_number'], $text_data['text']); 
        $response = json_decode($response);

        if(isset($response->body->messages[0]->{'error-text'}))
        {
            return array(  
                'status'   => 'fail',
                'response' => $response->body->messages[0]->{'error-text'} 
            );
        }

        return array(  
            'status'  => 'success'  
        );
?>
```

My research:

- I have tried sending to Philippine number, I successfully received the text message
- I have tried sending to US number, but I did not receive any text message, I don't know why.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send SMS to US numbers, You have to request short code or you have to registered long number. For more details you can check my answer on following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33035811/3077339

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the US you can only use a Nexmo virtual number as the sender, see this [helpdesk article](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204014883-Invalid-Sender-Rejection). From the code you posted it looks like you're using `'1FX Cash'`, which would be rejected.

My guess is that you're getting the `Error code 15 - Illegal Sender` error.

Comment: What is an example for virtual number as a sender? 1FX Cash works actually fine sending to philippines

Answer (score 0):

Is this a brand new Nexmo account? By default when you first sign up you can only send text messages to the phone number you registered with. You'll need to contact their support to request the restriction to be removed before you can send to others. I think you can do that here: https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: I have already deposit $10 in my account which means its not demo anymore.