# anybody know how receive sms to php script using nexmo sms api

Tags: php, mysql, api, sms, vonage

am trying to implement nexmo sms api to receive sms from phone and save to mysql table. i took account in nexmo. i ckeched the documentation. but confused how to use it

```
https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api
am trying to implement nexmo sms api to receive sms from phone and save to mysql table. i took account in nexmo. i ckeched the documentation. but confused how to use it
```

anybody knows how to receive sms to my script when sending sms from phone,then please help me
i want to fetch sms to script and save to mysql table

```
public function myinformation() {
   $request = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

// Check that this is a delivery receipt.
if (!isset($request['messageId']) OR !isset($request['status'])) {
    error_log('This is not a delivery receipt');
    return;
}

//Check if your message has been delivered correctly.
if ($request['status'] == 'delivered') {
    error_log("Your message to {$request['msisdn']} (message id {$request['messageId']}) was delivered.");
    error_log("The cost was {$request['price']}.");
     $From = $this->input->post('saleena@gmail.com');
        $ToEmail = $this->input->post('saleena@gmail.com');
        $message = "Results: " . print_r( $request, true );
           $this->load->library('email');
        $subject = 'My Attempt';

        // Get full html:
        $body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=' . strtolower(config_item('charset')) . '" />
    <title>' . html_escape($subject) . '</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
' . $message . '
</body>
</html>';
      $result = $this->email
                ->from($From)
                // Optional, an account where a human being reads.
                ->to($ToEmail)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->message($body)
                ->send();

        var_dump($result);
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        exit;      

} elseif ($request['status'] != 'accepted') {
    error_log("Your message to {$request['msisdn']} (message id {$request['messageId']}) was accepted by the carrier.");
    error_log("The cost was {$request['price']}.");
} else {
    error_log("Your message to {$request['msisdn']} has a status of: {$request['status']}.");
    error_log("Check err-code {$request['err-code']} against the documentation.");
}
    }
```

i tried this code.but i didnt receive any mail to my mail

Comment: receive SMS from phone ? or receive delivery report form phone that your msg has been delivered or not ?

Comment: receive SMS from phone

Comment: refer this link : https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/conversion-api

Comment: i read this,but didnt understnand

Comment: have tierd anything?

Comment: i read this, i understood that we have to set a callback url. if we set a callback url,then we send sms from our phone ,then it wil get to this url action?

Comment: please join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127879/gurusoni1

Comment: refer this link aswell , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007597/how-to-send-text-to-us-numbers-in-nexmo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127880/discussion-between-soni-vimal-and-saleena).

Comment: good debuging.. :)

Comment: hmm :) hello @devpro

Comment: I just do it, you need to set up the callback URL in your dashboard to point to your website page where your code is, then in that page, you can copy and paste their code.it will works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nexmo's SMS API which allows you to send a text in over 200 countries with a simple HTTP call.

**You can sign up for a virtual number which allows you to send SMS messages & receive incoming message as well.**

For 2FA, you can use the Verify API to authenticate users to a specific device.

This method is more secure than using an SMS API and randomly generating numbers yourself. The pin will then entered by the end user & checked by the Verify API.

It takes a few lines of code to use either of these APIs. Below is a block of code in PHP which allows you to send a text using the SMS API.